# What are the possible ways of validating whether all element displayed or not

Tags: geb

When I hover the mouse on button, then many options are displayed. Now I want to validate that all the options are displayed or not at single time.

```
static content = {
    timeRangeContainer { $("div.filter-list")[0] }
    timeRangeFilterOptions { timeRangeContainer.find ("div.filter-drop li")}
}

def hovermouse(){
       interact{
             moveToElement(timeRangeFilterButton)
}

def optionDisplayed(){
     timeRangeFilterOptions[0].isDisplayed()
}

}
```

In the above example, I can check only one element whether it displayed or not , But I want to check all the options are displayed or not at single line of code such as (timeRangeFilterOptions.isDisplayed()). Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be:

```
boolean optionsDisplayed(){
    timeRangeFilterOptions*.displayed.every()
}
```

Comment: What would be the opposite of this? For example, verifying that dropdown list is not shown. I have a case where `waitFor {!dropDownList.present}` fails randomly for me, where static content is `dropDownList (required:false, wait: false) {$('.menuItem')}`

Comment: I would suggest adding a new question instead of asking this in a comment.